# Pattern combinators in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, c#-9.0

Can I use the [pattern combinator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3#pattern-combinators) concept in a LINQ statement? If yes, can you exemplify? For example as following,

```
var query =    from invoice in _context.Invoice
/* here -> */  where  invoice.InvoiceDate is >= request.BeginDate and <= request.EndDate
               select new yaddayaddayadda { ... }
```

Comment: Sure just Google Linq.

Comment: That's not legal; pattern matching only works on constants. When you do use constants, pattern matching works in LINQ to Objects but not generally, because expression trees do not (yet?) support them (i.e. you can't write `Expression<Func<int, bool>> x = i => i is >= 2 and <= 4;`).

Comment: I removed the newly created tag `pattern-combinator` before it can run off and lead an ill-gotten life of its own; the feature is called "pattern matching" and the things it works with are called "patterns". "Pattern combinators" are, as far as I can tell, not yet a thing.

Comment: Welp, turns out I'm wrong -- the specific use of `and`, `or` and `not` in patterns *is* called a [pattern combinator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3#pattern-combinators) by the docs. I don't think it deserves its own tag, but it is a thing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert no problem sir, it will arise someday, it is inevitable though you don't concur with.